# GKE & Stackdriver & Spring - logs not grouped/correlated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, spring-cloud

This question is gonna be a hard one to ask as there are multiple technologies involved. Feel free to ask for more info as I may unintentionally leave out an important piece of the puzzle. :)

I have:

- **Spring Boot** application
- with logging configured by **[Spring Cloud GCP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#log-via-console)** project
- deployed into **GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine)**
- and exposed to the internet by **[GKE Ingress for HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)**

I can confirm every single piece of the setup working correctly. When I access my public IP address, I'm shown my Spring Boot application and in Logs Explorer I see logs in the expected format (JSON, not default plaintext).

However, what I am missing is seeing request information in my container logs. This is what my logs look like:

[image]

The first log message you see is from Cloud HTTP Load Balancer. The second one is from Kubernetes Container. As you can see, the first one is containing `httpRequest` and the data within it. Although the trace ID of the first message is matching the second one, there is no `httpRequest` info being shown for container logs.

According to what I read, the request information should be propagated down the line and I should be able to see it in my container logs alone.

Please advise.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you log your information or whatever to stdout then info would be visible in Logging.
Log everything u need from the container and then explore in Logging Dashboard.

I would also suggest if the setup is somewhat production like, have another project dedicated specifically for logging purposes and you can use log sinks in order to stream your logs to another project.

You can also save money with this approach, if you set the retention periods properly. (below you might see the results of the optimization)

[image]

**One more note**  don't forget about Debug property in Docker.yaml file.

Hope that somewhat helps.

And also would suggest looking @

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```